# Coverting the url object to json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I'm getting the response from my third party like the below

[https://app-pv.myfamily.com/myconnect/myapp/myDetails?myDetailsNbr=U123763673&source=myAppsearch&error=[[Error%20in%20object%20%27myStatusModel%27:%20codes%20[claims.correct.adjust.notsubmitted.27myStatusModel,myApp.correct.adjust.notsubmitted];%20arguments%20[];%20default%20message%20[This%20Claim%20has%20an%20Corrected%20Claims%20which%20is%20not%20yet%20approved.]]]](https://app-pv.myfamily.com/myconnect/myapp/myDetails?myDetailsNbr=U123763673&source=myAppsearch&error=%5B%5BError%20in%20object%20%27myStatusModel%27:%20codes%20%5Bclaims.correct.adjust.notsubmitted.27myStatusModel,myApp.correct.adjust.notsubmitted%5D;%20arguments%20%5B%5D;%20default%20message%20%5BThis%20Claim%20has%20an%20Corrected%20Claims%20which%20is%20not%20yet%20approved.%5D%5D%5D)

I have to parse the default message array in the url link at the end
%20default%20message%20[This%20Claim%20has%20an%20Corrected%20Claims%20which%20is%20not%20yet%20approved.]

and show the error msg inside it.I've used split method but I can get only the url its not giving the last array. I've tried to remove the %20 using replace but I'm unable to get the default message array.

```
 var str = "https://app-pv.myfamily.com/myconnect/myapp/myDetails?myDetailsNbr=U123763673&source=myAppsearch&error=[[Error%20in%20object%20%27myStatusModel%27:%20codes%20[claims.correct.adjust.notsubmitted.27myStatusModel,myApp.correct.adjust.notsubmitted];%20arguments%20[];%20default%20message%20[This%20Claim%20has%20an%20Corrected%20Claims%20which%20is%20not%20yet%20approved.]]]";
  var url = str.replace(/%20/g, "");
  console.log(url.find,'ppp')
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  The url does not contain any json.  Yet, you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to get the error text.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. @Yogi, can you please re-open it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)